# MySql Group By Count item count Distinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table looks like

```
id  user_id  level

1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     3        1
```

Here user id 1 exist in level 1 and level 2
Now when we count group by level then in counting we want ignore user_id  1 from level 1 cause it exist another group.  we want to consider only one group existing and higher group.

I have done only group count but cant understand how ignore counting.

My current query is

```
select 'level', DB::raw('count(*) as total') from table GROUP BY level
```

My Query return  counting

```
level      total

1             3
2             1
```

But I want looks like

```
level      total

1             2
2             1
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with a working query in (your brand of) sql, and *then* figure out how to express that in your framework

Comment: try this.. `DB::table('table')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total','level')->distinct('level')->groupBy('level')` i hope it will work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this query and this gets the desired output
check it out:

```
select T2.MLevel, COUNT(*) as total
  from (select  max(T1.level) as MLevel
    from YourTable as T1
      group by T1.user_id ) as T2
group by T2.MLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select 'level', DB::raw('count(*) as total') from table GROUP BY level HAVING level = 1 AND user_id != 1
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value because they miss an opportunity to educate and empower thousands of future researchers.